# add time when the marker is created with info window

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have a code that makes a marker everytime it gets a gps data from the saved txt file and then makes a marker every 5minutes I would like to make an info window for every marker where the contents of the infoWindow is the time that that marker was created. Any thought on where I should augment the infoWindow?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(10.294097000000000000,123.897455799999990000);
    var marker;
    var map;
    var mapProp;

    function initialize()
    {
        mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:17,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
        setInterval('mark()');
    }

    function mark()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var file = "gps.txt";
        $.get(file, function(txt) { 
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                console.log(lines[i]);
                var words=lines[i].split(",");
                if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!=""))
                {
                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                          clickable: true,
                          position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),
                          });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));
                    //document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML=words[3];
                    //document.getElementById('course').innerHTML=words[4];
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<b>Speed:</b> ' + Date + ' knots'
          });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    info.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.info.open(map, marker);
            });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: What infowindow?  Your code doesn't create one.

Comment: oh Im sorry i copied the code with no info Window... just edited it now so it has infoWindow

Comment: Is the 'speed' content you've got in the info not needed, or do you want the date added to it?

Comment: nope speed info is not needed. I only need to put the date on when the marker is created per Marker created

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change the content value:

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: new Date().toString()
});
```

Which will give you something like `"Tue Jan 21 2014 10:48:10 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"`

BTW, there's no need for this line:

```
setInterval('mark()');
```

Just use:

```
mark();
```

Comment: I just changed it but there was no more map